# Export PDF document all pages to A4 size Images using PDFBOX (PDF document which contains different page sizes like A3 and Letter )

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I tried by using the below code which I coped from here : [link](https://gist.github.com/mmdemirbas/209b4bdb66b788e785266f97204b8631)

But that code is for adding the multiple different size images to pdf.

I just wanted reverse process of that to export different sizes of pdf document pages to Images like how above link is doing.

```
private static void exportPDF_To_Images(File sourceDir, String destinationDir) {
    try {
        File outputfile = null;
        File destinationFile = new File(destinationDir);
        if (!destinationFile.exists())
            destinationFile.mkdir();

        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(sourceDir, MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly());

        PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
        String fileName = "Export_Image";

        for (int page = 0; page < document.getNumberOfPages(); ++page) {

            outputfile = new File(destinationDir + File.separator + fileName + "_" + (page + 1) + ".png");
            BufferedImage bim = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(page, 300);

            ImageIOUtil.writeImage(bim, destinationDir + File.separator + fileName + "_" + (page + 1) + ".png", 300);

            PDImageXObject image = PDImageXObject.createFromFile(destinationDir + File.separator + fileName + "_" + (page + 1) + ".png", document);
            PDRectangle pageSize = PDRectangle.A4;

            int originalWidth = image.getWidth();
            int originalHeight = image.getHeight();
            float pageWidth = pageSize.getWidth();
            float pageHeight = pageSize.getHeight();
            float ratio = Math.min(pageWidth / originalWidth, pageHeight / originalHeight);
            float scaledWidth = originalWidth * ratio;
            float scaledHeight = originalHeight * ratio;
            float x = (pageWidth - scaledWidth) / 2;
            float y = (pageHeight - scaledHeight) / 2;

            PDPage pdpage = new PDPage(pageSize);
            document.addPage(pdpage);

            try (PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(document, pdpage)) {
                contents.drawImage(image, x, y, scaledWidth, scaledHeight);
            }
            System.out.println("Added: " + destinationDir + File.separator + fileName + "_" + (page + 1) + ".png");

        }
        document.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at pdfbox samples. Example 1 of this link [https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.apache.pdfbox.tools.imageio.ImageIOUtil] seems to answer your question.

Comment: Please clarify what the problem is that you're trying to solve, or what goes wrong with the current code.

Comment: I wanted to download all sizes of pdf pages to a4 without cut of maatter.